# Dynamically adding constraints to variables in ruby

Tags: ruby, dynamic, instance-variables

I'm looking to dynamically add a constraint to a variable in ruby. I am reading in a rudimentary class specification from a file, which defines the class name, the attributes, and any constraints regarding the attributes. So for example it might be:

```
Class: Car
Attributes: model, String
Attributes: price, Fixnum
Constraint: model, model != nil
Constraint: price, price > 0
```

So I have written the following line which creates the class, and attr_accessors for the attributes:-

```
eval('class ClassName;  attr_accessor:var_1; def test() puts "Test class"; end   end')
```

But does anyone have any advice for adding the constraints? I wasn't sure whether rather than attr_accessors it would be better to have complete getter/setter methods which the constraints could be appended to?

Edit: Should add really new to ruby and pretty much self taught so please correct any silly mistakes or bad ideas.

Comment: I see no reason to use `eval()` here. You can dynamically create new classes using `Class.new()`.

Comment: This is quite a task for newbie. Did you make it up yourself or is this an assignment?

Comment: Anyhow, it'll help (you) a lot if you take your input file and write out, manually, the desired ruby code which would have been generated from it. Then the actual code generation is almost trivial (just compose a string and eval it)

Comment: Tip: incremental method body definition (adding those constraints one by one) is unnecessarily hard. Seems that you can just collect all constraints and generate the full method body at once.

Comment: I'd suggest to write per attribute setters, with an optional generic class method checking a given constraint(s). There are already some gems which do "type" checking but that's fairly simple to implement by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very unpolished gem for your need: [class_builder](https://github.com/Aetherus/class_builder).
It's unsafe (vulnerable to code injection) and probably buggy, and I will not maitain it. Just shed some light on you.

Please refer to the tests to see its usage.